# Jquery slider to show a div text when active

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the description text to show when the slider is active, currently it only shows when a thumb or main image is clicked.

I need some kind of active display:block on a div but I can't for the life of me work it out.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers,

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><a href="#" class="slide1"><img src="images/slider-images/slide1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="slide2"><img src="images/slider-images/slide2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="slide3"><img src="images/slider-images/slide3.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="slide4"><img src="images/slider-images/slide4.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="0" class="slide1" href="#"><img src="images/slider-images/thumbnails-1.png" ></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" class="slide2" href="#"><img src="images/slider-images/thumbnails-2.png" ></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" class="slide3" href="#"><img src="images/slider-images/thumbnails-3.png" ></a>
  <a data-slide-index="3" class="slide4" href="#"><img src="images/slider-images/thumbnails-4.png" ></a>

</div>

.detail {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    display:none;
    text-align: right;
    width: 845px;
}

      .bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    bottom: -95px;
  }

  .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 3px;
  }

  .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a:hover,
  .bx-wrapper .bx-pager a.active {
    border: solid #5280DD 1px;
  }

  .bx-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 120px;
  }



#bx-pager {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -92px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#bx-pager a {
    margin-right: 9px;
}
#bx-pager a.active img {
    border: solid 1px #ffffff;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto !important;

}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    background: none  !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    left:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: code please? some more info, and/or tried methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation: http://bxslider.com/options#onSlideAfter

> onSlideAfter
>
> Executes immediately after each slide transition.
>
> Function argument is the current slide element (when transition
>   completes).
>
> default: function(){} options: function($slideElement,
>   oldIndex, newIndex){ // your code here }
>
> arguments:
>
> $slideElement: jQuery element of the destination element
>
> oldIndex: element index of
>   the previous slide (before the transition)
>
> newIndex: element index
>   of the destination slide (after the transition)

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
  onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    var id=$($slideElement).attr('class');
    var detail="detail_"+id;
    $('.detail').hide();
    $('#'+detail).show();
  }
});
```

Also, use the `var` keyword in your functions. You are creating global variables when you omit the `var`.

Comment: Yep, just noticed this bit `slider.settings.onSlideAfter(slider.children.eq(slider.active.index), slider.oldIndex, slider.active.index);` in the jquery.bxslider.js code.  Was going to say the same thing!  Cheers :)

Comment: You jumped right to the code without looking for documentation first? I hadn't even considered that.

Comment: Sometimes it is faster than searching through documentation... to each their own